Error running anchor test: Unable to get latest blockhash
I'm getting a random inability to fetch a blockhash halfway through my test cases in anchor.
Can't see to find a patter to it. Can anyone help?
Test results:
  solchan-faucet
[DEBUG]: Starting before hook
[DEBUG]: Payer keypair generated EN7UPLvZuNWUNvL7gTsXe7hYUZ5xaBfChCgJgHc5UTTn
[DEBUG]: Payer funded with airdrop
[DEBUG]: Mint created BRxoTU59oPb8qpKCSCm2QksGrMrhLTuFKs2eJQi9QE7U
[DEBUG]: From token account created GLon227Nk99DAgPbdtUPPQaEstwbs9QshY9TXgepuzzp
    1) "before all" hook for "Fetches a new blockhash"


  0 passing (12s)
  1 failing

  1) solchan-faucet
       "before all" hook for "Fetches a new blockhash":
     Error: Unable to obtain a new blockhash after 10262ms
      at Connection._pollNewBlockhash (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5610:13)
      at Connection._blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5579:12)
      at Connection.sendTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5843:11)
      at sendAndConfirmTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21)

Contract:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount};

declare_id!("G5bmc1HnBS5wX5Xj2W6r2fEogD6gZcMURNp9HfRHYty4"); // Replace with your actual program ID

#[program]
pub mod solchan_faucet {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, faucet_amount: u64, time_limit: i64) -> Result<()> {
        let faucet = &mut ctx.accounts.faucet;
        faucet.faucet_amount = faucet_amount;
        faucet.time_limit = time_limit;
        faucet.owner = ctx.accounts.payer.key();
        faucet.last_distributions = Vec::new();
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_faucet_amount(ctx: Context<UpdateFaucetAmount>, new_amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let faucet = &mut ctx.accounts.faucet;
        faucet.faucet_amount = new_amount;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_time_limit(ctx: Context<UpdateTimeLimit>, new_time_limit: i64) -> Result<()> {
        let faucet = &mut ctx.accounts.faucet;
        faucet.time_limit = new_time_limit;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn distribute(ctx: Context<Distribute>) -> Result<()> {
        let clock = Clock::get()?;
        let user = ctx.accounts.user.key();

        // Gather necessary data before any mutable borrow
        let faucet_key = ctx.accounts.faucet.to_account_info().key;
        let seeds = &[faucet_key.as_ref()];
        let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

        {
            let faucet = &mut ctx.accounts.faucet;

            if let Some(distribution) = faucet.last_distributions.iter().find(|d| d.user == user) {
                if clock.unix_timestamp - distribution.timestamp < faucet.time_limit {
                    return Err(ErrorCode::TooSoon.into());
                }
            }

            if let Some(distribution) = faucet.last_distributions.iter_mut().find(|d| d.user == user) {
                distribution.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
            } else {
                faucet.last_distributions.push(Distribution {
                    user,
                    timestamp: clock.unix_timestamp,
                });
            }
        }

        // Perform the transfer after mutable operations are done
        let cpi_ctx = ctx.accounts.into_transfer_context().with_signer(signer);
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx, ctx.accounts.faucet.faucet_amount)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = 8 + 32 + 8 + 8 + 32 + 8 * 200)] // Adjusted space for the struct
    pub faucet: Account<'info, Faucet>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateFaucetAmount<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
    pub faucet: Account<'info, Faucet>,
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateTimeLimit<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
    pub faucet: Account<'info, Faucet>,
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Distribute<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub faucet: Account<'info, Faucet>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

impl<'info> Distribute<'info> {
    fn into_transfer_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, token::Transfer<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = token::Transfer {
            from: self.from.to_account_info(),
            to: self.to.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.faucet.to_account_info(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(self.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts)
    }
}

#[account]
pub struct Faucet {
    pub faucet_amount: u64,
    pub time_limit: i64,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub last_distributions: Vec<Distribution>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Distribution {
    pub user: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Too soon to request tokens again.")]
    TooSoon,
}

Tests:
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { SystemProgram } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createMint, createAccount, mintTo, getAccount } from '@solana/spl-token';

function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

describe('solchan-faucet', function () {
  this.timeout(300000); // Set the timeout to 300 seconds (5 minutes)

  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.local();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.SolchanFaucet;

  let mint: anchor.web3.PublicKey;
  let fromTokenAccount: anchor.web3.PublicKey;
  let toTokenAccount: anchor.web3.PublicKey;
  let faucet: anchor.web3.Keypair;
  let user: anchor.web3.Keypair;
  let payer: anchor.web3.Keypair;

  before(async () => {
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Starting before hook');

    // Generate a new keypair for the payer and fund it
    payer = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Payer keypair generated', payer.publicKey.toBase58());

    const airdropSignature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 10);
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Payer funded with airdrop');

    // Create a new mint
    mint = await createMint(
      provider.connection,
      payer,
      payer.publicKey,
      null,
      9,
    );
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Mint created', mint.toBase58());

    // Create token accounts for the faucet and user
    fromTokenAccount = await createAccount(provider.connection, payer, mint, payer.publicKey);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: From token account created', fromTokenAccount.toBase58());
    toTokenAccount = await createAccount(provider.connection, payer, mint, payer.publicKey);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: To token account created', toTokenAccount.toBase58());

    // Mint some tokens to the faucet account
    await mintTo(provider.connection, payer, mint, fromTokenAccount, payer.publicKey, 1000000);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Minted tokens to fromTokenAccount');

    // Generate a keypair for the user
    user = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log('[DEBUG]: User keypair generated', user.publicKey.toBase58());
  });

  it('Fetches a new blockhash', async () => {
    const { blockhash } = await provider.connection.getRecentBlockhash();
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Fetched blockhash', blockhash);
    assert.ok(blockhash, 'Failed to fetch blockhash');
  });

  it('Initializes the faucet', async () => {
    faucet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet keypair generated', faucet.publicKey.toBase58());

    await program.rpc.initialize(
      new anchor.BN(1000), // faucet_amount
      new anchor.BN(60),   // time_limit
      {
        accounts: {
          faucet: faucet.publicKey,
          payer: payer.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
          rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        },
        signers: [faucet, payer],
      }
    );
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet initialized');

    const faucetAccount = await program.account.faucet.fetch(faucet.publicKey);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet account fetched', faucetAccount);
    assert.ok(faucetAccount.faucetAmount.toNumber() === 1000);
    assert.ok(faucetAccount.timeLimit.toNumber() === 60);
    assert.ok(faucetAccount.owner.equals(payer.publicKey));

    await delay(1000);
  });

  it('Updates the faucet amount', async () => {
    await program.rpc.updateFaucetAmount(
      new anchor.BN(2000),
      {
        accounts: {
          faucet: faucet.publicKey,
          owner: payer.publicKey,
        },
        signers: [payer],
      }
    );
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet amount updated');

    const faucetAccount = await program.account.faucet.fetch(faucet.publicKey);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet account fetched after update', faucetAccount);
    assert.ok(faucetAccount.faucetAmount.toNumber() === 2000);

    await delay(1000);
  });

  it('Updates the time limit', async () => {
    await program.rpc.updateTimeLimit(
      new anchor.BN(120),
      {
        accounts: {
          faucet: faucet.publicKey,
          owner: payer.publicKey,
        },
        signers: [payer],
      }
    );
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Time limit updated');

    const faucetAccount = await program.account.faucet.fetch(faucet.publicKey);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Faucet account fetched after time limit update', faucetAccount);
    assert.ok(faucetAccount.timeLimit.toNumber() === 120);

    await delay(1000);
  });

  it('Distributes tokens', async () => {
    await program.rpc.distribute({
      accounts: {
        faucet: faucet.publicKey,
        from: fromTokenAccount,
        to: toTokenAccount,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        user: user.publicKey,
      },
      signers: [user],
    });
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Tokens distributed');

    const toTokenAccountInfo = await getAccount(provider.connection, toTokenAccount);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: To token account info', toTokenAccountInfo);
    assert.ok(Number(toTokenAccountInfo.amount) === 2000);

    await delay(1000);
  });

  it('Prevents distribution before time limit', async () => {
    try {
      console.log('[DEBUG]: Attempting to distribute before time limit');
      await program.rpc.distribute({
        accounts: {
          faucet: faucet.publicKey,
          from: fromTokenAccount,
          to: toTokenAccount,
          tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          user: user.publicKey,
        },
        signers: [user],
      });
      assert.fail('Expected an error to be thrown');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('[DEBUG]: Error as expected when distributing before time limit', err);
      assert.ok(err, 'Expected an error to be thrown');
      assert.equal(err.msg, 'Too soon to request tokens again.');
    }

    await delay(1000);
  });

  it('Allows distribution after time limit', async () => {
    // Wait for time limit to pass
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Waiting for time limit to pass');
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 120 * 1000));
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Waited for time limit to pass');

    await program.rpc.distribute({
      accounts: {
        faucet: faucet.publicKey,
        from: fromTokenAccount,
        to: toTokenAccount,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        user: user.publicKey,
      },
      signers: [user],
    });
    console.log('[DEBUG]: Tokens distributed after time limit');

    const toTokenAccountInfo = await getAccount(provider.connection, toTokenAccount);
    console.log('[DEBUG]: To token account info after second distribution', toTokenAccountInfo);
    assert.ok(Number(toTokenAccountInfo.amount) === 4000);
  });
});



This is very strange since it appears to be succeeding at first... since your tests are connecting locally, do you have any issues running a local solana-test-validator for a long period of time? I wonder if the test validator is crashing or getting killed in some way.

You might be getting rate-limited.
Try requesting the airdrop using the airdrop instead, of each time before the tests run.
Other possible things to try.

Check your local solana config and confirm the cluster to use is set properly solana config get

Try using another RPC provider like Triton or Helius and see if that helps.



Thanks! this was it.
